# Automatically suspend users from per-site metas

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, account-suspension

When a user is suspended from a SE site, it's usually going to be to stop them from causing trouble and give them a time out.  Currently the process doesn't suspend them from the sites meta, and gives them that avenue to continue to cause trouble.

Should a suspension on a site automatically suspend a user from their meta (and chat)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

Comment: no 15 char limit on answers i see

Answer (score 4):

If I recall correctly from earlier discussion in the chat, this is `[status-completed]`, though possibly not intentionally. Users need rep of >5 to participate in per-site meta activity, but suspended users' reputations are administratively set to 1 for the duration of the suspension, effectively disqualifying them.

Comment: correct, this already happens and was 110% intentional

Comment: @JeffAtwood, during the recent issue discussed in moderator chat, there seemed to be a notable period of time where a user who had 1 rep on the main site still had more than 500 rep on meta.  Is this just because it takes some amount of time to sync the rep?

Comment: @c.ross rep is synced hourly between child meta and parent

Comment: @Jeff So there can be up to an *hour* delay between suspension and the user not being able to access meta.  I think I could cause a lot of trouble in 30 - 45 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know that a suspension is always a good idea.  It might be a good idea *most* of the time, but probably not *every* time.  Sometimes the user will have legitimate questions about the circumstances surrounding suspension.

Instead, I think perhaps using the penalty box for their meta account might be better.

It would be interesting to see this expand to the chat rooms, as well.

Comment: There has probably been 1,000 posts saying that if suspended users wish to inquire about their suspension, they should ask via email.